# eslint: Parsing error: Unexpected token during import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

In a ReactJS app, I have an index.js file with the following imports:

```
export MainContainer from './Main/MainContainer';
export AboutContainer from './About/AboutContainer';
```

When I run ESLINT, I get the following error:

```
error  Parsing error: Unexpected token MainContainer
```

The error message is not referencing any of the eslint rules set up in .eslintrc.json. The app runs fine in Chrome with no console errors. Why is eslint  throwing the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have export instead of import while trying to import. Try:

```
import MainContainer from './Main/MainContainer';
import AboutContainer from './About/AboutContainer';
```

;)

If you're trying to re-export components, you'll need the braces:

```
export { MainContainer } from './Main/MainContainer';
export { AboutContainer } from './About/AboutContainer';
```

If it's re-exporting default exports:

```
export { default as MainContainer } from './Main/MainContainer';
export { default as AboutContainer } from './About/AboutContainer';
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider it a non-issue :)